# Why is this non-open ifstream still "good" after I try to extract from it?

Tags: c++, iostream

In GCC 4.7.0 20111217, [GCC 4.1.2](http://codepad.org/nhojwVXL), [GCC 4.3.4](http://www.ideone.com/ybRxD) and [GCC 4.5.1](http://www.ideone.com/7kciC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
   std::ifstream f;
   std::cout << f.get() << ", " << f.good() << ", " << f.bad();
}

// Output: -1, 1, 0
```

I'd have expected `-1, 0, 1` (which Clang 3.1 gives me), because of these paragraphs:

> `[C++11: 27.7.2.3]:`
>
> ```
> int_type get();
> ```
>
> 4 **Effects:** Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1). After constructing a sentry object, **extracts a character `c`, if one is available. Otherwise, the function calls `setstate(failbit)`**, which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4), 
>   5 **Returns:** `c` if available, otherwise `traits::eof()`.

and:

> `[C++11: 27.9.1.1/3]:` In particular:
>
> - If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.
> - If the file is not open for writing the output sequence cannot be written.
> - A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence.

Is GCC in the wrong here? Did an implementer misinterpret the "otherwise" in `[C++11: 27.7.2.3/4]`? Or did I misinterpret the standard?

Comment: I'd flag to delete, but I hazard to wager that this may help someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just realised I'm being silly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
   std::ifstream f;
   std::cout << f.get() << ", ";
   std::cout << f.good() << ", " << f.bad();
}

// Output: -1, 0, 0
```

Unspecified evaluation order. Duh.

Comment: (Note that `badbit` still isn't set; `failbit` is though.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the order that the operations on f is called is not specified by the standard.  The compiler is free to call `f.good()`, `f.bad()`, and `f.get()` in any order it chooses.

Try changing to print it on separate lines.